# JSF and SDO implementation for excel-like database management

Tags: java, jsf, db2, sdo

I am using IBM RAD to create my web apps and all is going well. However, I got a requirement to support the functionality mentioned in the title of this post. I tried googling but unlucky to find a solution, I would definitely appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't recommend a specific solution, but I think what you are looking for is commonly called a "data grid".

[Google search for: db2 data grid java](http://www.google.ca/search?q=db2+data+grid+java)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little bit late but RAD version 9 dropped out-of-the-box tooling support for SDO. RAD version 8 has it and uses the GUI to build the SDOs. The best "for beginners" book that documents the use of SDOs in RAD version 8 is "Beginning Java With Websphere": https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/beginning-java-with/9781430263012/